# How do I import / export social accounts using django import export package?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, django-import-export

I successfully imported and exported other data but not able to import/export social accounts and social application tokens. I am using django allauth for social account creation. There is no other way to login in.

[image]
[image]

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'channels',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'user_sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.sites',

'authapp',
'thanoschats',

'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',

'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
'import_export',
]
```

admin.py

```
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyUser

@admin.register(MyUser)
class UserProfileData(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Comment: Please share relevant and simplified code. For more information see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Done! Please help!